# Spring security - Move attributes from anonymous session to logged user session

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am writing web application using Spring MVC, Security. I would like to store some information for not logged users, and keep it in anonymous session. It will be some random uid, and some configurations that anonymous user could change. When user logs in, that data should be used in authentication using custom AuthenticationProvider.

1. How can I hook into Spring security anonymous authentication to put there UID?
2. How can I retrieve later the session while user is loging in?

thanks for any advices :)

Comment: So you mean something like allowing an anonymous shopping cart and then copying it when the person logs in?

Comment: Yes, this is very similar situation.